# Umbraco & goDaddy| error when trying to work with Umbraco back office

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco6, tinymce-3

Like the header says I am getting an error  when trying to work with Umbraco(6.2.1) back office

This is the error:

[image]

I already talked with goDaddy support, they says everything is OK from their side.

I flowed every "tutorial" I could find regarding this.

This is an error I am seeing in Goggle Chrome Console:
[image]

I am now clueless about what to do next.

*every help will be much appreciated.

---

**This is the config folder:**

[image]

---

**This is the -- [file](http://www38.zippyshare.com/v/69648418/file.html) -- it self**
[image]

Comment: This is becoming a problem out of scope of the "stackoverflow" Q&A.  Maybe try also the umbraco forums at http://our.umbraco.org

Comment: @dampee, I already posted 2 posts there and its getting nowhere http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/54801-TinyMCE-related-problem

Answer (score 0):

The error says you have an incorrect TinyMCE configuration. It will be a problem with that component and not the host. There is a [[Umbraco support ticket](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-608)] which suggested this may be fixed in release 6.2, but also a [[forum post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/45866-Rich-text-Editor-Returns-error-Incorrect-TinyMCE-configuration)] where its said this could happen in all versions, when a style-sheet which is registered in the database is deleted.

Comment: if i understand this issue, it could be happen if i add(mark) things to be added to the rich text editor(like text color) and adjusting the height and width size of the rich-text textBox, if so- can I overwrite those configuration changes? could you tell me what to overwrite?

Comment: When did this error occur? Did you make changes to the configuration which broke it? Do you have the original settings?

Comment: This is the first time that i uploading an umbraco project to goDaddy. in the local host env it is working fine. I thought maybe to download fresh umbraco install and take the necessary files.

Comment: Was the problem related to the Issue mentioned in the text?

Comment: @dampee, what do You mean? I didn't get an answer yet, and still want to solve this issue.

Comment: Ok.  Was it an upgrade or a complete new website?  Are other pages (without the RichtTextEditor working?)

Comment: @dampee, it is a new website(first "Umbraco") that I uploaded to "goDaddy" and yes other pages work. but it is a problems because I used RichText in almost every page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the files are present in the deployed `/config/` folder? Check that there is a `/config/tinyMceConfig.config` file present.

Comment: And not only the tinymceConfig.config, but ALL files.  I think it has to do with missing files on your website.

Comment: @Digbyswift, I added an image of the files in the config folder to the initial post, I have checked and they are all there(20 files).
you have another suggestion?

Comment: What is the contents of the file?

Comment: @dampee, I added the file to the post